# Is there any way to tell whether the shot is going to hit you or not?

Tags: superhot

In *SUPERHOT*, I keep dying disproportionately to grazing shots.

Make no mistake: I also die to head-on-no-doubts-about-it direct shots, shots in the back, multiple shots from multiple angles that I run into when trying to dodge other shots, and melee weapons.

But often, even when there's only a single enemy shooting a single shot at me, I think the shot is going to go beside me, but instead it hits my hitbox and kills me.

**Is there any way to tell whether the shot is going to hit the player character or not?**
I recall having a vague feeling that some bullets and/or bullet-trails look different than others, so I'm not sure if there's some color-coding that I'm missing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*To my knowledge*, there is no exact way to tell if a bullet will graze you or not. My general rule of thumb is perpendicular motion for half a second or so, always favoring more over less time.

Slight spoilers on the bullet trails below

> I think what you're referring to with bullets is if a bullet is very close to you and you are holding the katana it will change color allowing you to click it to cut the bullet in half nullifying it.

Comment: Ohhh, so *that's* what the bullet trail was probably about. Also, the half-second rule sounds definitely useful.